# Joomla creating and calling multiple views

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm a wordpress developer trying out a Joomla component build.

My issue is, I'm trying to understand how to incorporate multiple views within a component.

For example, producing a list of entries in one view, and then when one of those entries is selected forwarding to another view that produces a single entry.

I understand php enough to know how to get the hyperlinks done dynamically, but I don't know how to declare the two separate views in Joomla.  Will each view require it's own model? (I assume not.) Does any of that make sense?

Like I said, Joomla newb, any links or references are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, each view should have it's own model. As for forwarding to another view, this should be done in the controller, however should be done with 2 separate views. Once the task has been performed, set it to redirect like so:

```
function your_function(){
    $msg = JText::_( 'Operation Successful' );
    $this->setRedirect( 'index.php?option=com_hellowworld&view=hellowworldview', $msg );
}
```

Obviously you will need to change **"com_hellowworld"** to the name of your component and **"hellowworldview"** to the name of the view you want to redirect to.

Have a look through the documentation for [Developing an MVC Component for Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5). It will guide you through in detail, all the basics of developing your component.

Hope this helps.